# How do I check if a string in a file contains certain characters?

Tags: python

I'm creating a function that goes through a file and creates a dictionary for strings that appear with certain characters. I'm not sure how to see if a string contains at least three of the specific characters we're looking for. If a string contains the characters, a, b, c or d, and contain 3 of them, then I add it to my dictionary. However, the string can contain them in any order, and that's what I'm struggling with, finding each string that contains 3 of them in any order.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the code you have tried into your question. Make it a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Try to check Python's `in` keyword. Question though, would you take occurrence of the letter/character into consideration? And please post what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there are many approaches. Here is one, using sets - a built-in type. This does not take into account letter frequencies. For frequencies, collections.Counter could be used

```
abcd = "abcd"
set_abcd = set(abcd)
test_string1 = "String with abcd"
test_string2 = "String without"

for s in [test_string1, test_string2]:
    if len(set(s).intersection(set_abcd))>3:
        print(s, "contains any three of", set_abcd)
    else:
        print(s, "does not contain any three of", set_abcd)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) for this, one possible implementation:

```py
>>> target_chars = {"a", "b", "c"}
>>> input_string = "z e r i t c b"
>>> input_chars = set(input_string)
>>> len(target_chars - input_chars) == 0
False
>>> target_chars - input_chars
{'a'}
```

`len(target_chars - input_chars)` is true iif the input string contains all the target characters.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using for loops:

```
characters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for line in lines:
    count = 0
    for character in characters:
        count += 1 if character in line else 0
    if (count >= 3):
        # do something here
```

For incrementing the count by the amount of times the character appears in the string:

```
count += line.count(character)
```

Comment: Hey that works great, except for how do I add it to the dictionary if lets say the character c appears 2 or 3 times in the word? It's only working if it has 1 of each

Comment: I updated my original answer with an alternative solution for the situation you described.